# Working with barcode fonts in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, barcode

I need to create labels in Microsoft Word 2010 with numbers encoded as barcodes. The barcode's format (ean, code39, upc, etc) does not matter. I have downloaded a barcode conversion font that I found at [this site](http://www.morovia.com/free/code39-font/).

When I type the number that I want and then I format it with my new font, it produces a barcode. I then print it on an OKI laser printer (1200 dpi). The result seems to be fine, at least for common people.

But, when I try to scan it, nothing happens. I tried both with a barcode scanner and a data collector, but neither of them read the barcode. My barcode scanner is working fine, because I can read commercial barcodes printed on products.

Does anybody have any advice? How do I do this kind of stuff? I want to do it using Word because I will generate labels using Mail Merge. Therefore using external programs aren't option for me.

Comment: Can you scan them off the screeen in word? can you scan them off the screen in something like notepad? are you forgetting the start and end characters?

Comment: What Jake223 said, you'll need a start bit http://www.idautomation.com/code39faq.html

Comment: Yeah, it worked, thanks. @Jake223, answer the question, so I can mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to add start and stop characters, see http://www.3sindustries.com/barcodes/codabar.php or google for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some recommended solutions:

1. Read some articles on how to generated barcode in Word, e.g. [Use Microsoft Word as a Barcode Generator](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/free-barcode-generator/)
2. Try to use some other third-party software on barcode generation in Word, e.g. [Barcode for Microsoft Word](http://barcodelib.com/word_barcode/main.html)
3. Read some posts in other forums, e.g. [Barcode symbology 128 font](http://boards.fool.co.uk/barcode-symbology-128-font-11177270.aspx?sort=whole#11177270)

Answer (score 0):

To reinforce what others are saying you need to understand the defined format for the type of barcode you are trying to print.  For example Code 128 requires a START and STOP character as well as a CHECKSUM.  If you have not included these as part of your data string then the barcode scanner will not make any sense of your barcode.  Some other things to consider with barcode fonts are -

Quite zones - you need white space before and after your barcode.

Font spacing - only print with fixed font spacing.  Any auto spacing may make your spaces to wide or too narrow between the bars.

Comment: you are answering a 3 year post, original person who asked the question might have long forgotten